# Decrease height of title bar of apps without switching theme on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gtk, titlebar

[image: example]

How do I decrease height of the title bar of apps without switching theme?

Answer (score 8):

The above did not work for me... but I got good results
with the following in my file ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css :

```
 /*
 * Reduce height of window header (title?) bars.
 * Seems enough to specify padding, no need to repeat
 *   padding-left padding-right padding-top padding-bottom
 * nor it seems necessary to even mention
 *   margin-top margin-bottom
 */

.default-decoration {
    min-height: 0px;
    padding: 3px;
}

.default-decoration .titlebutton {
    min-height: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are using Gnome 3 -

1. Open or Create the file : `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` (`~` is the home location for your current user. For example, if your user is `demo`, then `~` would represent `\home\demo`)
2. Add the following CSS to the file

   ```
   headerbar entry,    
   headerbar spinbutton,    
   headerbar button,    
   headerbar separator {    
       margin-top: 0px; /* same as headerbar side padding for nicer proportions */    
       margin-bottom: 0px;    
   }    

   headerbar {    
       min-height: 24px;    
       padding-left: 2px; /* same as childrens vertical margins for nicer proportions */    
       padding-right: 2px;    
       margin: 0px; /* same as headerbar side padding for nicer proportions */    
       padding: 0px;    
   }
   ```
3. Run `ALT+F2` and provide the letter '`r`' in the dialog box that appears that  and hit enter to refresh the style

For more info, refer the original solution from Unix Stackexchange : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276951/how-to-change-the-titlebar-height-in-standard-gtk-apps-and-those-with-headerbars?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I combined the recommendations of R.S and of Paul Szabo, and this appears to have given me a few additional pixels.