# How can I customize my terminal window look?

Tags: 18.04, themes, customization

I'd like a way to customize the Terminal window without changing the theme itself:

[image: screenshot]

1. Change the three top right buttons icons
2. Set opacity on all other windows top bar

Current Theme: Flat-Remix-GTK-Blue-Dark

Comment: How do you install this theme? :   ) I installed from the file but its look not like yours.

Comment: You could try using CSS to achieve this. For example, something similar to what you require can be found here - [Decrease height of title bar of apps without switching theme on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034404/decrease-height-of-title-bar-of-apps-without-switching-theme-on-ubuntu-18-04/1034452#1034452).

Comment: @αғsнιη https://youtu.be/BLVtxpm5c2A?t=1357 at 22:37

Comment: @R.S I won't be messing with CSS for now, I think there might be things to mess with in dconf editor or Tweaks but I don't know where exactly..

Comment: Not for theming of individual applications. You will be messing with .css for that.